# Google fused location service android

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, service

1. class name is Myclass and implement methods like -> LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener override methds

```html
 private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;
    Context mContext;



    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

        createLocationRequest();
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) mContext);

    }


    private void createLocationRequest() {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        // mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(2);
        // mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    }

    @Ov
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();

    }

    public String updateUI() {

        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            Double lat = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
            Double lng = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();

            Log.d("thhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh",lat.toString() +lng.toString());
            getCurrentlocation(mCurrentLocation);
           //setCurrentLocation(String.valueOf(lat + "," + lng));
tLocation(mCurrentLocation);
           // arrayList.add(mCurrentLocation);

            return lat.toString();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void getCurrentlocation(Location mCurrentLocation) {

    }

    public void setmCurrentLocation(Location mCurrentLocation) {
        this.mCurrentLocation = mCurrentLocation;
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    }
```

I want to develop mylocation class and getlocation method so its returns lat loan.
How to access that in any class and get lat lon ??

Comment: make a service and use it to get the location in any class you want. but please try to do some thing and then post your doubt. this is not how you ask questions in stackoveflow.

Comment: Alright I post my code but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

may you need to create servics, that implement google locationAPI , Location listner more..

In that override method onLocationChanged you get lat-long now you can send that direct to your server or other class

i hope My answer is help you.

if don't then ask me again.
thank you.

Comment: You mean I need to create service an

Comment: this is possible in two way using activity-fragment and service

Comment: If i need to show map with current location and also send lat long to server so that time I need to create service ( for send data to server  ) and also implement fused location API in map fragment to show current location with updates??